# macos shell script not returning control

Tags: shell, perl

I'm running a Perl script on High Sierra which calls a bash shell script using the 'system' command, but it is not returning control back to the Perl script.

```
@sysCmd=('~/bin/2mp3.1.sh');
system(@sysCmd) == 0 || die "system command failed: $?\n";
```

My understanding of 'system' is that unlike 'exec', it is supposed to return back to the calling script.
The bash script:

```
for i in *.flac ; do
    ~/bin/ffmpeg -i "$i" -acodec libmp3lame "$(basename "${i/.flac}")".mp3
    sleep 1
done
```

Once that is finished, the Perl script should pick up where it left off and continue, but no joy.
Would appreciate some ideas please. I'm wearing asbesto pants just in case :)

Comment: Re "*Once that is finished, the Perl script should pick up where it left off and continue*", It does. `system` will returns as soon as the shell exits.

Comment: How long did you wait for it to finish, and how long does that bash program take when you run it directly on the same inputs?

Comment: When it's run from CL in Terminal it finishes about 12 conversions in a few minutes, and does go back to a prompt. From the  Perl script I can watch the .mp3 files being created in Finder but even when they're all completed, the Perl script does not pick up where it should. It seems to be hanging up with the script somehow.

Comment: I've taken out the 'sleep' command and added 'exit 0' after the done. .mp3 files are created, but control isn't passed back to Perl.

Comment: Does `system` seem to hang when calling any other commands or scripts?  Put `echo` commands in you shell script to print out a message of what it's doing between every line.  Does `system("~/bin/2mp3.1.sh")` make any difference?  Is `~/bin/2mp3.1.sh` really resolving to the file you think it is?  What is the shell script's shebang line?  I'm just trying to think of ways to constrain the problem.

Comment: Try adding the `-nostdin` option to ffmpeg, to see if it makes a difference

Comment: lordadmira, good ideas. I've had previous scripts working before this with no problems, but then ran into a problem with a particular .flac file so had to find a different method. As far as I can tell yes, it is working on the list of files in order. I can watch them in Finder being created. The shebang is '#!/bin/sh'. I'll try you other suggestions.

Comment: mivk, tried that but it failed without any conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Find the tty of the perl command running the script and then execute:

```
tty=ttyOfPerlCommandRunningYourScript
while [ 1 ]; do
   clear
   date
   ps -ft $tty
   sleep 1
done
```

If the tty of the perl script is something like `/dev/ttys010`, then set `tty=ttys010`.

Since the child shell script is globbing its files, then you can execute `ls *.flac | nl -ba` and find the position of the file currently executed by `ffmpeg` to get an estimate for how much longer the shell script will continue running.

You can press `control-C` to terminate the above `while` loop. You can also use the up and down arrow keys to cycle through your command history to restart that loop.

At any iteration of the above `while` loop you should see the child `bash` command and any of its children. If the child `ffmpeg` command is currently executing, then the filename on that command line represents the current file being processed. Search the `ls` command's output to see where you are in the current progress.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Made your 1st script as above. Then ran the 2nd CLI, but still not sure what it means - this is a new level for me.
/Volumes/Backup3/httpd/public/local/music/data/Shakatak/View From the City (1998) [user] ls *.flac | nl -ba
     1 01 Nova Bossa.flac
     2 02 Drive-in.flac
     3 03 Magic.flac
     4 04 Sundown.flac
     5 05 Get Up.flac
     6 06 Driftin'.flac
     7 07 Move a Little Closer.flac
     8 08 Say What You Want.flac
     9 09 Slammin'.flac
    10 10 It's Alright.flac
    11 11 Steveland.flac
    12 12 Say Somethin'.flac

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
Changed the conversion script to one using 'flac' instead of 'ffmpeg'.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040323004759816
# flacmp3 - convert a flac file to mp3
#
if [ "$1" ]
then
  for file
  do
    if [ -e "$file" ]
    then
      /usr/local/bin/flac -c -d "$file" | /usr/local/bin/lame -h -m s -b 192 - "$(basename "$file" .flac).mp3"
    else
      echo >&2 "No such file: "$1""
      exit 1
    fi
  done
else
  echo >&2 "Usage: "$(basename "$0")" INPUTFILE [...]"
  exit 1
fi
```

Problem SOLVED. But I'm still trying to determine why it was failing before.
Many thanks to all who took some time to on a special day to spend on this.